# Configure keys that trigger intellisense completion in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I would like Visual Studio to autocomplete the current entry in the intellisense menu only when I hit tab.

Autocompletion being triggered, for example, when I press a period, is forcing me to hit escape every time I'm writing something that cannot yet be autocompleted, to avoid that what I'm typing gets replaced with a random entry.

Is there an option to configure this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and programming in C#.

[image: autocomplete example]

Example: here I'm typing `Log`, which is a class for which I haven't yet added the appropriate `using` statement. None of the suggestions is the good one. If I hit `.` now, the autocomplete feature will write `EventLogProcessor`, which is not what I want.

Please note that this question has nothing to do with VIM, this is not a duplicate of the question linked at the top.

Comment: @BoteaBogdan: what does vim have to do with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `Toggle Between suggestion and Standard completion mode` option of `visual studio` .. It will now only `suggest`  .. and if you press `Tab` it will complete your choice ..

> Edit -> IntelliSense -> Toggle

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks... I cannot understand why it's not with the other options :)

Comment: This works perfectly for Visual Studio 2019. "Edit"->"IntelliSense"->"Toggle completion mode".

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2012, from the Menu Bar,

1. Select Tools -> Options
2. In the left pane, expand Text Editor -> C#
3. Select InteliSense

The characters that commit are listed in a text box

Comment: Yes but you cannot add the Tab character.

Comment: Tab completes for me, although I don't know if that is from Resharper. If you remove all the characters from the box, it should still work.

Comment: I cannot see this option, actually... maybe it's for a different version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct. I'm using 2012, so not applicable to you. I've edited the answer