# Configure VS2015 Intellisense "accept" key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Without disabling Intellisense's automatic prompting (via Toggle Completion Mode), I'd like to only "accept" the prompt when pressing a specific key. At the moment, a variety of keys will "accept" the prompt, specifically including shift+9 or '(', which prevents the creation of a new method without first pressing 'Esc' to get rid of the prompt.

Comment: It's possible that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758154/configure-keys-that-trigger-intellisense-completion-in-visual-studio) helps, and you can also try the shortcut Ctrl-Alt-Space to toggle auto-highlight.  This may not be ideal if you still want Intellisense to highlight the matching item but just ignore `(` as a completion character.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298292/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-keyboard-options

Comment: @pcdev It is a duplicate of that! My bad.